# raphael.js IE8 transparent stroke

Tags: internet-explorer-8, transparency, raphael, vml

I created a sunny sky with two objects following a random transparent path with `raphaël.js`:

http://jsfiddle.net/vcX4U/1/

This works fine in all proper browsers:
[image: Good Sky]

Only IE8 - which I have to support due to the WinXP-users - shows a black path and flipped gradients on the upper sun rays (which is not critical):

[image: Bad Sky]

I am pretty sure this has to do with `raphaël.js` using VML for IE6-8, and SVG for all other browsers. But that may be an explanation not a solution...

Ideas?

edit @amadan: Thanx for your effort. But this makes the planes "crash":

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only a partial solution for now, but

```
var c = paper.path(route).attr({stroke:"transparent","opacity":"0.01"});
```

fixes your stroke issue. I'll have a look at the ray issue later.

Comment: I think you'll find that if you run your fiddle twice on IE, with or without the above change, your planes crash :(

Comment: Actually I don't "use" the planes at all. For my real project it is a little devil followed by an angle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8xGT/3/ and as you can see in my update http://jsfiddle.net/Y8xGT/4/ it works perfectly with `.attr({opacity:0})`! Thanks again!